# DLLs specific to .Net version?

Tags: .net, dll, mono

When you ship a .Net program as a compiled .EXE, it's specific to a particular version of .Net (and corresponding version of Mono) - not e.g. "4.0 or later" but exactly 4.0.

Does the same applied to compiled DLLs?

Suppose your program needs some third-party libraries, which you ship as DLLs. If you then want to upgrade your program to use a later version of .Net/Mono, do you have to build or acquire correspondingly updated versions of the DLLs also?

Comment: Nobody can tell what the next version of .NET is going to look like.  Your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every new version of .NET can reference assemblies created in older version except all the BCL assemblies.
You dont need to acquire newer versions of third-party libraries.

For example if you build a project with .NET 4 you can reference a library created with .NET 3.5 (MyAssembly.dll version 1.0.0.0) but you cannot reference System.Xml.dll version 3.5.0.0. You will have to reference System.Xml.dll version 4.0.0.0